# Nestjs/prisma/docker/postgres - app worked yesterday but now keeps saying "cannot find module '/app/dist/project-name/src/main'"

Tags: typescript, docker, nestjs, prisma

I am building a backend using nestjs, docker, Postgres and prisma. yesterday I was able to run the app fine. but now I try running npm run start:dev. it says the code is compiling with 0 errors. but then I am getting an error that says:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/app/dist/backend - ameenazon/src/main'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

I'm not sure what is causing this. again, the app was running fine less than 12 hours ago. I don't know what I changed between now and then. I am following this [tutorial](https://www.prisma.io/blog/nestjs-prisma-rest-api-7D056s1BmOL0#development-environment). I also tried changing `"incremental": true,` to `false` in my tsconfig.json file but that didn't help. I tried changing `"start:prod":"node dist/main"` to `"start:prod":"node dist/src/main"` in my package.json but that didn't fix anything.

to my knowledge I have not significantly deviated from it. I think I was getting this error yesterday but I'm not sure how I fixed it.

here's the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15.2
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  api: 
    image: node:18.16.1
    volumes: 
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    command: ['tail', '-f', '/dev/null']


volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```

here's the package.json

```
{
    "name": "project-name",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "",
    "author": "",
    "private": true,
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "scripts": {
      "build": "nest build",
      "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
      "start": "nest start",
      "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
      "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
      "start:prod": "node dist/src/main",
      "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
      "test": "jest",
      "test:watch": "jest --watch",
      "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
      "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
      "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
      "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
      "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.1.0",
      "@nestjs/passport": "^10.0.0",
      "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
      "@nestjs/swagger": "^7.1.1",
      "@prisma/client": "^4.16.2",
      "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
      "passport": "^0.6.0",
      "passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
      "password-generation": "^1.1.0",
      "prisma": "^5.1.0",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
      "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
      "swagger-ui-express": "^4.6.3",
      "ts-password-generator": "^1.0.6"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@nestjs/cli": "^10.0.0",
      "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.0",
      "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.0",
      "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
      "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
      "@types/node": "^20.3.1",
      "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.9",
      "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
      "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.11",
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.11",
      "eslint": "^8.42.0",
      "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
      "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
      "jest": "^29.5.0",
      "prettier": "^2.8.8",
      "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
      "supertest": "^6.3.3",
      "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
      "ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
      "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
      "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
      "typescript": "^5.1.3"
    },
    "jest": {
      "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "js",
        "json",
        "ts"
      ],
      "rootDir": "src",
      "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
      "transform": {
        "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
      },
      "collectCoverageFrom": [
        "**/*.(t|j)s"
      ],
      "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
      "testEnvironment": "node"
    },
    "prisma": {
        "seed": "ts-node prisma/seed.ts"
    }
}
```

link to the rest of the [project](https://github.com/amustafa15/backend-ameenazon). so yeah it was working yesterday and now it isn't. not sure why. not sure how I fixed it before but any help would be appreciated.